# Date and Time Split, then added into another table column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, phpmyadmin

**EDIT:**

I want to thanks @jimmix for giving me some idea to get started on my last post, But unfortunately, my post was put on hold. Due to the lack of details.

But here are the real scenario, I'm sorry if I didn't explain well my question.

From my CSV file, I have a raw data,  then I will upload using my upload() function in into my phpmyadmin database with the table name "tbldumpbio",

See the table structure below:(tbldumpbio)

[image]

From my table tbldumpbio data, I have a function called processTimesheet()

Here's the code:

```
public function processTimesheet(){
        $this->load->model('dbquery');          

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbldumpbio");

            foreach ($query->result() as $row){

            $dateTimeExplArr = explode(' ', $row->datetimex);

            $dateStr = $dateTimeExplArr[0];
            $timeStr = $dateTimeExplArr[1];

            if($row->status='C/Out' and !isset($timeStr) || empty($timeStr) ){
                $timeStrOut ='';
            } else {
                $timeStrOut = $dateTimeExplArr[1];
            }

            if($row->status='C/In' and !isset($timeStr) || empty($timeStr) ){
                $timeStrIn ='';     
            } else {
                $timeStrIn = $dateTimeExplArr[1];   
            }

            $data = array(
                'ID' => '',
                'companyAccessID' => '',
                'name' => $row->name,
                'empCompID' => $row->empid,
                'date' => $dateStr,
                'timeIn' => $timeStrIn,
                'timeOut' => $timeStrOut,
                'status' => '',
                'inputType' => ''       
            );              
            $this->dbquery->modInsertval('tblempbioupload',$data);


            }
    }
```

This function will add another data into another table called "tblempbioupload". But here are the results that I'm getting with:

Please see the below data:(tblempbioupload)

[image]

The problem is:

- the date should not be duplicated
- Time In data should be added if the status is 'C/In'
- Time Out data should be added if the status is 'C/Out'

The expected result should be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see is that you have a time expressed as 15:xx:yy PM, which is an ambiguous format, as one can write 15:xx:yy AM and that would not be a valid time.

That said, if what you want is that every time the date changes a row should be written, you should do just that: store the previous date in a variable, then when you move to the next record in the source table, you compare the date with the previous one and if they differ, then you insert the row, otherwise you simply progress reading the next bit of data.

Remember that this approach works only if you're certain that the input rows are in exact order, which means ordered by EmpCompId first and then by date and then by time; if they aren't this procedure doesn't work properly.

I would probably try another approach: if (but this is not clear from your question) only one row per empcompid and date should be present, i would do a grouping query on the source table, finding the minimum entrance time, another one to find the maximum exit date, and use both of them as a source for the insert query.

Comment: +1. Date time being stored that way is indeed strange as it is military time. And storing the data in the way it needs to be accessed makes the most sense.

Comment: I think if only 0-12 AM and 0-12 PM are used, that would be ok, but I'm pretty sure any SQL server would refuse something as 15:00:00 AM in a time/datetime field...
I don't understand your commend on storing data the way it needs to be accessed...

Comment: im not the asker